# Ironpython import in python script

Tags: python, vb.net, ironpython

When using ironpython in vb.net i am calling a python script.  That script needs to import some packages (for example import html2text at the top of the script).  On this machine i have python and pip and I have the package installed, but when running this script through ironpython it says it is unable to find it (no module named html2text).

So, when using ironpython, where does it look for the packages?  how do I install these packages?

Comment: _when using ironpython, where does it look for the packages_ `import sys; print (sys.path)`

Comment: When putting that into my python file i get IronPython.Runtime.List

Comment: ah, so i've printed out the individual parts of that list out and found that it was looking in a Lib folder.  I've now added the modules I wanted (selenium) and I'm getting the error "No module named warnings"

Comment: How are you installing packages?  I've never used Iron Python, so I don't know the usual method.  Are you using pip?